# Using the twitter API in Django

Tags: python, django, twitter, django-views, python-twitter

I've been using python twitter tools to automate stuff (automatically add tweets to favourite etc.). This is very useful, so I thought i'd turn it into an open-source program called "Mojito". Problem is i'm not an expert in python/django, and i'm stuck here:

This is my form used to collect two variables: mKeyword (the keyword to look for on twitter) and mCount (how many tweets):

```
from django import forms

class GetVariables(forms.Form):
    mKeyword = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    mCount = forms.IntegerField(max_value=100, min_value=1)
```

I then have a "mojitoform" function that uses python-twitter-tools' auto_fav function. Both are below:

```
def mojitoform (request):
try:
    form = GetVariables(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
    mKeyword = form.cleaned_data['mKeyword'] 
    mCount = form.cleaned_data['mCount']
    success = True
    tweets = auto_fav( mKeyword, mCount)['text']
except:
    notLoggedIn = True
return render (request, '../templates/dashboard.html', locals())
```

This is the "auto_fav()" and "search_tweets()" function:

```
def auto_fav(q, count=100, result_type="recent"):
    """
    Favorites tweets that match a certain phrase (hashtag, word, etc.)
    """
    result = search_tweets(q, count, result_type)
    for tweet in result["statuses"]:
        try:
            # don't favorite your own tweets
            if tweet["user"]["screen_name"] == TWITTER_HANDLE:
                continue

            result = t.favorites.create(_id=tweet["id"])
            print("favorited: %s" % (result["text"].encode("utf-8")))

        # when you have already favorited a tweet, this error is thrown
        except TwitterHTTPError as e:
            print("error: %s" % (str(e)))


def search_tweets(q, count=100, result_type="recent"):
return t.search.tweets(q=q, result_type=result_type, count=count)
```

My problem is: when I run the mojitoform, it doesn't take into account the "mCount" variable. Only one tweet is favourited everytime. This is weird because the auto_fav() script works fine when I run it on SHELL, but on django it'll always ignore the mCount variable.. I've twisted this every way around, i'm lost.

Comment: Can you show the GetVariables form definition?

Comment: Hi Daniel, just added it to the post. Cheers

Comment: Hi, sorry to insist but has anyone found anything? Still haven't figured it out...

Comment: So the one bit of code you haven't posted is `search_tweets`. What is that? It does not seem to come from python-twitter-tools.

Comment: You're right, i forgot to mention that one. It's pretty basic, i just added it.

Comment: Thanks. You probably need to add some debugging. Are you sure that the count is being correctly passed through the different functions? Try printing it in each of them. Then have a look at the JSON that is returned. Does that have multiple statuses, or only one? That will help to narrow down where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Great advice, cheers, i'll have a look